# Div title shows just one time

Tags: html, mouseover

I'm using this code:

```
<div id="m1" class="drag"; title="CARS"
   style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:32px; height:32px;">
 <img src="http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/wp-content/uploads/mapicons/shape-default/color-ff8a22/shapecolor-color/shadow-1/border-dark/symbolstyle-white/symbolshadowstyle-dark/gradient-no/sportscar.png"
   width="32" height="32" alt="" />
</div>
```

when I get the mouse over it shows correctly the title CARS, then I drag the marker to the google maps, a new marker replaces the one I've just dragged but the title CARS does not show again at the same place where the original marker was.

Is there a way to fix this? I've tried this.title but it makes the marker undraggable.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the title to the img, not the div

Edit:

I think the fault is in your javascript.

```
// Append icon
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = obj.firstChild.getAttribute("src");
  img.style.width = "32px";
  img.style.height = "32px";
  m.appendChild(img);
  drag_area.replaceChild(m, obj);
```

I think you are missing

> img.title = obj.firstChild.getAttribute("title");

Comment: Thanks Bondye for your response, could you please tell me where do I have to put the title="CARS" exaclty?

Comment: Thanks Bondye but no luck, i'm using this example: http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/drag-from-outside.html

Comment: Thanks again Bondye, i'll try this , if it does not work i'll leave it with the title just showing once. Thanks for your help! EDit: It wokrs like charm! Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe he means like this

```
<div id="m1" class="drag"; style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:32px; height:32px;"><img title="CARS" src="http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/wp-content/uploads/mapicons/shape-default/color-ff8a22/shapecolor-color/shadow-1/border-dark/symbolstyle-white/symbolshadowstyle-dark/gradient-no/sportscar.png" width="32" height="32" alt="" /></div>
```

I moved the title attribute from the div to the image.

Comment: Thanks for your response , unfortunately it makes the same result.